# Secure ZIP is giving error while trying to extract excel files from zip

Tags: windows-7, zip, archiving, extract

Here I am trying to extract excel file from a zip file, which is giving below errors.
 I don't have option to use either `7-zip` or `winzip`

Secure zip error console

[image: Secure zip error console]

**Edit-1** : 
integrity test result

[image: integrity test result]

Comment: Got the same :(

Answer (score 0):

There may be various causes to this. 
Try to use a different destination path like C:\temp . Make sure you have write access privileges where you want to extract the files.

Comment: even if i try extracting to different destination, i am getting the same issue. i am sure i have write access.

Comment: Can you test archive integrity ?

Comment: There should be an option in the SecureZip menus. Or you can try unzip -t YourArchiveName.zip.